# How Does This Sample Menu Set The Height

Tags: html, css

I found this menu sample on W3Schools.  I'm trying to create a menu bar on my MVC layout page.  My was looking very sloppy and I liked how this one looks.  I pasted it into my website and it works as shown, but I don't understand how it is being styled.  I don't see any height or vertical alignment settings.  Is it the padding style that does it?  Are ul and li tags commonly used for this kind of menu?  I would have used something like a span tag to do this and not ul or li tags.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}

li {
    float: left;
    border-right:1px solid #bbb;
}

li:last-child {
    border-right: none;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #111;
}

.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li style="float:right"><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Height set by `padding` in `li a`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The height is being set by the default CSS styling in addition to some padding applied to the links. The default CSS height for the `ul` element is `auto`, meaning that it will fill space (i.e. be as tall) as its children.

What this means is that it is taking the `font-size` / `line-height` of the links and adding `padding`, which is 14px on both top and bottom. That height becomes the height of the entire list / navigation bar.

Comment: Thanks.  Would you say it's common to use ul/li elements for a menu or is it more common to use something else, maybe span?

Comment: In my *opinion*, it is common to use ul/li elements for a menu. For HTML semantics, the menu is an unordered list (ul) with line items (li), which makes sense. It also *may* make sense to wrap that unordered list inside of a `nav` (navigation) element.